# how to show images in RDLC report?

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

i have a column were i want the image to come out but at run-time only the name appears

> MIMEType:  image/jpeg Source:  Database Value:  =Fields!Image.Value

i saw this code but idk were to put it:

> MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
>
> Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
>
> return ms.ToArray();

please help

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
        Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(10, 10);
        public byte[] MyPicture
        {
            get
            {
                // Generate bitmap


                // Convert to stream
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                __img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```